# Is there leading/trailing constraints in flutter widget instead of left/right?

Tags: ios, flutter

I develop a Flutter app that supports RTL and LTR.

I come from "iOS constraints world" and when I add a widget to the canvas in Flutter, I use the left/right properties, for example, when I add padding from the left.
But padding from the left is not padding from the leading side, that this is what I wanted (left for LTR and right for RTL), and when I switch between English lang to RTL lang I get weird "constraints" (using the localization library).

What is the correct way to put the widgets in the canvas that it will support what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(start, top, end, bottom),
```

or

```
EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 42.0),
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.